# How can I say for each image fill input value with the path of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, laravel

I got this code

```
<div id="image-zoom">
    <img src="{{url('/')}}/images/answers/{{ $option->id }}/medium/{{ $option->image_path   }}" class="answer-image-create" id="image{{ $i }}">
</div>
<input onchange="readURL(this, {{ $i }});" type="file" name="image_path{{ $i }}" id="image"/>
```

And the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var image_src =  $('#image-zoom  img').attr('src');
        alert(image_src);
    }; 
</script>
```

On Edit(Update) is showing me four images, just fine, on alert is showing me the path only the first one, how can I do to take the path for each image and than to fill the input with that path or src..because I need the input to be filled so that image wont be lost when I type submit(edit), because only the ones that I click upload file input are editting the others go lost Thank you if someone helps me..

Comment: You really must struggle with this part.. input can't be filled with jquery or any other library. You need to show what you have tried.. we can only see 1 img.. and I guess you have the same id for every block..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and I may not, in your onload function you are looking to get the src attr for each img? If that is the case the issue is that `.attr` returns the attribute for the first element in the matched set (see - http://api.jquery.com/attr/). What you can do is iterate through the matched elements to get each src. Something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var image_srcs =  [];
    $('#image-zoom  img').each(function(index, elem) {
        image_srcs.push($(this).attr('src');
    });
    // do something with the array of img srcs you have
};
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect it turns me all four images, If I am not asking to much I need this image_src to put that value to the input, like this <input value="//here to come that image_src value ", hope you can understand me, again thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to fill an input with type `file` from javascript.